# Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module java.base and module jrt.fs

Tags: java

private JFrame frame;

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI window = new GUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Console:

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module jrt.fs and module java.base

I'm trying to create a GUI on Eclipse using windowbuilder and all the time i run into the same error and i can't launch my class to create a JFrame.